# Truth value of proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have the following propositions, is one of them true?

> $\forall_y\in\mathbb{Z}, \forall_x\in\mathbb{Z} (\forall_z\in\mathbb{Z}(x*z=y*z \implies x=y))$
>
> $\forall_y\in\mathbb{Z}, \forall_x\in\mathbb{Z} (\exists_z\in\mathbb{Z}(x*z=y*z \implies x=y))$

It's very confusing, my thinking is that the second one is true but it depends on how you interpret the expressions...
Thank you.

Comment: both are false. the first *would* be true if the innermost "("-bracket was right before the $\forall_z$-quantor and the innermost ")"-bracket was before the $\Rightarrow$. the second statement is false since you can always pick $z=0$.

Comment: But exists means there is at least one option, so why not choose z=1 for the second statement?

Comment: take $x=1$ and $y=2$.
of course there exists $z$ such that $x*z=y*z$ (pick $z=0$)
but that does **not** imply $x=y$.
thus the statement is wrong

Comment: What you are said proves the first statement is false, isn't it?

Comment: stop. i am confused now. give me some moments to think about my comments. my comment proves the second wrong - i think.

Comment: I am wrong, you are right. i got confused by the brackets. the second one is true by picking $z=1$

Comment: But isn't the second proposition false? The claim is that for any choices of $x$ and $y$ there is always a $z$ such that whenever $x * z = y * z$ it is also the case that $x = y$. Though it is possible to satisfy the antecedent (by picking $z=0$), if we chose $x \neq y$ the proposition fails to be true for *any* possible choice of $z$.

Comment: But we need one choice of $z$ in the second one, not every choice.

Comment: Ah, *now* I read it correctly. I agree with both of you: if $x$ and $y$ are distinct we can always choose a $z$ to make the implication  "false => false" (i.e. true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a mis-step, I think I now read both propositions correctly: as discussed in the comments above by @Max and @MathStudent, the first proposition is false while the second proposition is true.

The first proposition fails because we can choose infinitely many triples $(x, y, z)$ of integers such that $x * z = y* z$ and yet $x \neq y$. Specifically, 
whenever $z = 0$ but $x$ and $y$ have already been chosen to be distinct, then the antecedent is true but the consequent is false.

To see that the second proposition is true, it might be clearer to consider the two cases for possible choices of $x$ and $y$:

1. $x = y$
2. $x \neq y$

We now need to check there exists a $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x*z=y*z \implies x = y$.

If (1) holds, then choosing $z = 0$ means that both $x*z=y*z$ and $x = y$ are true, so the whole proposition is true.

If (2) holds, then choosing any $z \in \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$ will mean that the antecedent $x*z = y*z$ is false and the consequent $x = y$ is false. Since "false implies false", the whole proposition is again true.